# Update a SQL Server table in one server from another server in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatables

So I have two `SqlConnection` objects in C# viz. `connection1` and `connection2` that are for two different databases on separate servers. For a clearer picture, sample connection strings for these connections are as follows:

```
ConnectionString1 = @"Data Source=Server1;Initial Catalog=Database1;User ID=UID1;Password=Password1"

ConnectionString1 = @"Data Source=Server2;Initial Catalog=Database2;User ID=UID2;Password=Password2"
```

Both the databases (`Database1` and `Database2`) have a table `Employees` which has the same schema, columns, etc. `DataBase2` basically holds a copy of `Database1`. So any changes made in `Database1.Employees` table have to be updated in `DataBase2.Employees` table as well.

I have tried using `SqlBulkCopy` class for this and it is working perfectly. But it doesn't seem to be ideal for large databases because before copying the data from source table to destination table, I have to delete the contents first and then copy the contents. Is there any other alternative way that I could use to update the table?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the edit Marc! Will keep this format in mind..As you can see I am fairly new here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ConnectionString1 = @"Data Source=Server1;Initial Catalog=Database1;User ID=UID1;Password=Password1"
INSERT INTO [DatabaseName1].[dbo].[TableName]
SELECT FieldName
FROM OPENDATASOURCE('SQLNCLI',
'Data Source=Server2;Initial Catalog=Database2;User ID=UID2;Password=Password2')
.DatabaseName2.dbo.TableName
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply Jeeva. Will this command work when trying to **update** the destination table from source table?